# Cannot retrieve post data because of 301 moved permanently error

Tags: http-status-code-301, opayo

Response from the API is lost because of 301 moved permanently error.

```
<form action="https://test.sagepay.com/mpitools/accesscontroler?action=pareq" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MD">
  <input type="hidden" name="PaReq">
  <input type="hidden" name="https://examplewebsite.com/en/applicant/terms-page">
</form>

<script>
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
```

[Network console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7azks.png)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to update your callback url to the new url and avoid the 301 error. If thats not possible, you might have to configure your app server to do a 307 redirect instead of 301 so that the post data is preserved.

You can look up more on the redirection based on the webserver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

301 moved permanently issue is resolved by changing the url to /terms-page/ from /terms-page"